# How to disable text area through html helper

Tags: c#, html, css

How to disable a text area that uses html helper? Where do I put the attibute "disabled"?

```
  <div class="md-form">
      <label for="tx_justificativa " class="mb-4 triangulo">Digite sua justificativa:</label>
      @Html.TextArea("tx_justificativa", @item.tx_justificativa, new { @class = "md-textarea form-control", @id = "tx_justificativa", @maxlength = "500", @style = "min-width: 100%", @rows = "5" })
  </div>
```

Comment: @disabled = "disabled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it was a little obvious. Sorry.

```
 <div class="md-form">
     label for="tx_justificativa " class="mb-4 triangulo">Digite sua justificativa:</label>
     @Html.TextArea("tx_justificativa", @item.tx_justificativa, new { @class = "md-textarea form-control", @id = "tx_justificativa", @maxlength = "500", @style = "min-width: 100%", @rows = "5", disabled = "true" })
 </div>
```